# Visual Studio pre-increment bug

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Found a weird behaviur on my code.

Code:

```
char foo[] = {64, 1};
int i = 0;

char c = ((foo[i]) | (foo[(++i)]));

cout << "Text: " << c << " " << (int)c << endl;
```

Results:

```
Text: ☺ 1
```

I was specting "Text: A 1" instead of "Text: ☺ 1". For some reason the compiler is ignoring the "| foo[++i]" part.

Well the solution for this is quite simple, it would just take another line, but **what I'm interested in is to know if this is a compiler bug or just c++ being weird**.

Tested in VC10 and VC11.

edit: Added () to the code, still the same behaviou.

Comment: The order of the evaluations in `foo[i] | foo[++i]` is not specified. There are many questions about similar problems, e.g. [Undefined behavior and sequence points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points). In your particular case, I guess `i` is first incremented (`++i`), and then you get `c = foo[1] | foo[1]`, which is `c = 1 | 1`, i.e. `c = 1`. Note that relying on unsequenced operations does not only make results hard to predict, but can cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: @jogojapan @jprofitt its not an eveluation ordening problem, because the result is the same when I do something like this `char c = ((foo[i]) | (foo[(++i)]));`

Comment: @TheVTM Brackets don't change the situation. You still have two arguments to the `|`-operator, and the order of evaluation for operator arguments (as well as function arguments) isn't specified by the Standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of expression(not well-formed formula) is not documented in C++ standard. It depend on compiler behaviour. For example:

```
push(pop() * pop());
```

C++ doesn't document the order of calling `pop()`. So results are different in MSVC and GCC. You should call `foo[i]` and `foo[++i]` step-by-step.